# Por que minhas páginas de erro personalizada não estão sendo chamadas?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

A minha página de erro personalizada não está sendo chamada.

- SO: Linux Ubuntu
- PHP 7 / Laravel 5.5
- Já criei a pasta "resources/errors" e nela o arquivo "404.blade.php"
- Já dei permissão no SO para a pasta
- Já usei os comandos "php artisan cache:clear" e "php artisan view:clear".
- Troquei no arquivo .env a opção "debug" para false.

Enfim, essas foram as ações que eu tomei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu acho que à partida o erro está no path para a pasta errors, esta deve estar em `resources/views/errors`.

Exemplo para teste:

 - Cria ficheiro `404.blade.php` dentro da pasta que mencionei acima

 - Aceder a um url que não esteja definida em `app/HTTP/routes.php` ou `routes/web.php` (em versões mais recentes do Laravel) e confirma se vai para esta nova pag `404.blade.php`

A partir daí podes personalizá-la como quiseres.

Comment: Miguel foi exatamente isso. Eu li a documentação e não me atentei a este detalhe. Realmente o arquivo deverá ficar em "resources/views/errors".
Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @AlexandroSantos