# Redirecionar p/ nova página ao ocorrer erro 404 usando Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

Qual a forma correta do Laravel 5.6 redirecionar outra rota caso seja erro 404?

Criei a pasta **resources/views/errors/** e o arquivo **404.blade.php**,
e funcionou certinho, mas
não quero exibir o erro, quero que seja redirecionado para outra página.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um script dentro da pagina `404.blade.php` para fazer este redirecionamento, desta forma:

```
<script>
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
</script>
```

Ou alterar o arquivo `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` do `Laravel`, na linha onde contem o seguinte trecho de código:

```
return response()->view('core.layout::error', ['code' => 404, ...
```

Onde você pode colocar a rota que você quiser no lugar de 'core.layout::error'.

Comment: Não encontrei essa linha, acho que na versão 5.6 não existe mais. Vou ficar com o JS mesmo. Valeu Wictor!

Comment: @LuisAlberto e Wictor, talvez isto ajude a esclarecer mais um pouco: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232812/por-que-minhas-p%c3%a1ginas-de-erro-personalizada-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a3o-sendo-chamadas/232822#232822 . É dentro desse ficheiro que o Wictor falou que podes colocar esse JS

Comment: Miguel, foi exatamente isso que fiz, mas acho que ficaria melhor usando o sistema do Laravel. Valeu!